# HP ENVY 17-1050ea Notebook PC screen flickering when I connect charger to my notebook

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I am looking for solution of my problem. I own HP ENVY 17-1050ea Notebook PC, it works perfectly fine but the only issue I am facing is SCREEN FLICKERING. I only happens when I connect my charger to my machine.

Screen only flickers when I logon to windows. I have windows 7 Home Premium. I have never experience any flicker on screen while in BIOS or windows startup. And when I remove charger everything goes fine.

I have ATI RADEON 5850 graphic card in my system. I have updated to latest drivers and also run HP recovery many times but no luck.

help needed.

Comment: It looks like a firmware issue Try to update the BIOS.http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/Hp-envy-notebook-17-screen-flickering-done-some/td-p/4117784

and 

http://www.andyfox.net/hp-envy17-problems-solved/

Answer (score 0):

Might be some interference caused by the net's frequency. Did you try plugging in your charger the other way around (i.e. flipping poles)? (Serious suggestion.)

Some chargers and/or cases aren't properly isolated, so there might be some minor voltage on components that shouldn't have any. For example, when I plug in my Asus Transformer Prime, the metallic case will have some minor voltage depending on the charger's orientation in the wall outlet.

Comment: I tried it by inverting orientation but problem still exists