# Screen flicker on HP dv6t-7000

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display

My laptop screen flickers - it is difficult to find a pattern for why. It flickers once it gets warmer. It flickers if I slap the side of the computer. It does not flicker when I move the lid back and forth. It does not flicker if I move the screen cables. It flickers a lot sometimes and not at all other times.

There are other people with similar screen flickering that was caused by differing reasons - it seems to be across all laptops

- many relate to a VGA Cable Problem [hp pavilion dv6 Screen flickering](https://superuser.com/questions/1091999/hp-pavilion-dv6-screen-flickering) and there is a nice video of fixing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlA0oveG7-Y
- some think it is an inverter board https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/82063/Screen+flickers+and+turns+off,+inverter+or+inverter+board and on Mac too [Screen Flicker on a black MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/217186/screen-flicker-on-a-black-macbook)
- some think it is related to the BIOS and others think it is electrical interference [HP ENVY 17-1050ea Notebook PC screen flickering when I connect charger to my notebook](https://superuser.com/questions/886252/hp-envy-17-1050ea-notebook-pc-screen-flickering-when-i-connect-charger-to-my-not)
- some think it is the settings set too high [Screen flickering on Windows 8.1 HP laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/975397/screen-flickering-on-windows-8-1-hp-laptop)
- there is a huge number that think it is the Nvidia drivers https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/4ypcvs/screen_flickering_still_an_issue_with_latest/ but this seems to say it is not [Screen Flicker on Windows 10 with Multiple Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/1117347/screen-flicker-on-windows-10-with-multiple-monitors)
- it often goes unanswered [Flickering laptop screen when hot - cause?](https://superuser.com/questions/1006807/flickering-laptop-screen-when-hot-cause?rq=1)

I tried a few things

- I lowered the refresh settings
- I changed Nvidia drivers, tried six from across the last year as well as the latest
- I went into device manager and removed my Nvidia card (stops the flicker)
- I pulled the screen bezel and checked the screen cable is connected (it looks like OEM tape so I left it alone)
- I pushed on the screen cable to see if it does anything (it did not)
- I slapped the side of the screen (it caused it to flicker)
- It does not flicker in the BIOS http://ccm.net/forum/affich-102262-screen-flickering-issues-can-be-diognosed even if I slap the side of the screen
- The flicker is either the Nvidia gpu or the Nvidia driver: I booted into the BIOS to check for flicker, there was none. I then booted into the OS and there was flicker. I then removed the GeForce video card from the device manager, the flicker then stopped. This means the integrated gpu is fine.

I did not try changing the screen resolution

Interesting enough - the flicker seemed to all happen exactly when I rolled back the Nvidia driver because the newest driver caused Minecraft to crash. I think it was a coincidence the flicker started at the exact same time. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2791170-game-ended-with-bad-state-exit-code-1073740791

I made a video of the flicker here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WNIYAXX1Cc&feature=em-upload_owner#action=share

Comment: it has been two weeks and the flicker has not resolved -- yesterday I updated to the latest Nvidia driver but it made no difference; I have the Nvidia gpu disabled so the laptop is usable

Comment: I pulled the screen and checked the cable - everything looked fine and I don't think the cable had ever been removed previously (tape looked clean)

Comment: for the record, it still flickers; I have gpu-z installed, on startup once gpu-z launches the flicker stops -- don't ask me why or how I found this